# Select entire data(which is going to be interpolated) along with the braces (eg. {{name}}) in a summernote-angular(air-mode)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, summernote

In the below code snippet `'data.text'` is a string which has data that gets interpolated by `$interpolate` of `angular`.
Eg. `"My name is {{name}}"`

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Other Options</label>
    <summernote config="summernoteConfig" ng-model="data.text"></summernote>
</fieldset>
```

Summernote is initiated in airmode. So now the user can select certain part of the data and style it. 
The problem is when the user selects data within the curly braces and applies some style the angular throws error:

> Syntax Error: Token 'span' is an unexpected token at column 2 of the
>   expression [partner_name] starting at [span
>   style="text-decoration-line: underline;">partner_name].

Now I have figured out two ways to tackle this problem:

**Solution 1:** On receiving error from angular, alert the user about the selection and take the string back to it's original form.

**Solution 2:** When user selects the data withing curly braces, select the curly braces as well forcefully.

In "Solution 2" how can I know which text get selected in order to force select the brackets. Are there any events in `summernote-angular` to achieve this?
How do I select the whole text along with the braces when part of data within the braces is selected?

If there is any other way with which I can tackle this problem, please assist me.

Thanks in advance...